# How to get end date from start date and days using JQuery UI datepicker

Tags: html, jquery

I have this code in my application using JQuery-UI datepicker:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.start_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    duration: 'fast',
    minDate: +1,
    yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
  });
  $('.end_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    duration: 'fast',
    minDate: +1,
    yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
    enableOnReadonly: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<input type="text" id="start_date" placeholder="Start Date" />
<input type="number" id="daysNumber" placeholder="Days" />
<input type="text" id="end_date" placeholder="End Date" readonly/>
```

I used this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $( ".no_of_days" ).change(function() {
            var periodval=$(".no_of_days").val();
            var startDate = $('.start_date');
            var endDate = $('.end_date');
            //endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + periodval);
            var dte = startDate.datepicker("getDate"); 
            dte.setDate(dte.getDate()+periodval); 
            endDate.datepicker("setDate", dte);

          });

            $( '.start_date' ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,      
                showAnim: 'slideDown',
                duration: 'fast',   
                minDate: +1,
        });

            $( '.end_date' ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,      
                showAnim: 'slideDown',
                duration: 'fast',   
                minDate: +1,
                yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
                enableOnReadonly: true,
            });
    });
</script>
```

but this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: endDate.getDate is not a function

and this is highlighted:

> endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + periodval);

I have seen some examples, but not really going for JQuery UI.

How do I

1. onchange daysNumber get end_date from start_date and Days (daysNumber)
2. and also on select start_date with the value of daysNumber get end_date

using JQuery-UI datepicker

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  Getting / setting dates in a jquery-ui datepicker?  https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate or adding/subtract days to/from a date?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/563420/2181514

Comment: @freedomn-m - but this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: endDate.getDate is not a function

and this is highlighted:

> endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + periodval);

Comment: See the API link: should be `endDate.datepicker( "getDate" );` and similar for `.datepicker("setDate")`

Comment: @freedomn-m - I added this: endDate.datepicker("setDate") + periodval;        but notthing is happening, and no error on the console

Comment: `var dte = startDate.datepicker("getDate"); dte.setDate(dte.getDate()+1); endDate.datepicker("setDate", dte);`

Comment: @freedomn-m - When I used the sample you gave me it works, but when I changed the 1 in it to periodval it didn't work and no error.  See the modification in my code

Comment: @freedomn-m - Thanks. It works